# Used Automator to automatically insert file path; now "~a" is substituted with "ã"

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator

I used Automator to automatically insert a certain file path to my terminal whenever I press a certain shortcut. My AppleScript looks like this:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "/Users/johnappleseed/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/University"
    return input
end run
```

The problem is: Whenever I press the shortcut assigned to this Automation in my Terminal, the "com~apple" in the inserted text is replaced with "comãpple". Therefore, I get an error message because that file path does not exist.

Do you have any idea how I can get around this "~"-replacement?

Comment: On my system it types it exactly as written. What version of **macOS** are you running and and what are your **Language & Region** _settings_ in **System Preferences**? Also what its your  **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Input Sources** set to?

Comment: @user3439894 I can reproduce this, with Region Switzerland, preferred language English and Input Source "Swiss German". It doesn't occur if I switch the input source to US-english. Obviously, switching Input Sources to make this work is not an option :-)

Comment: I have macOS Monterey 12.0.1. My language is set to German (so is my language in Input Sources) and my region is set to Germany.

When I copy the file path as usual (in "Finder" by pressing "option" after I right-clicked a folder), it gets inserted normally in my terminal. The problem only occurs when I use this shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to fix this!

This automation doesn‘t work like copy and paste. It "mocks" the user and "presses" the exact keys as in the string. On my keyboard, when I press *⌥N* and then *A*, I get "ã". However, when I press *⌥N* and then *Space* and THEN "A", I get "~a". So the solution is to add a space after the ~:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "/Users/johnappleseed/Library/Mobile Documents/com~ apple~CloudDocs/University"
    return input
end run
```

Comment: Only problem with that is that it will fail for input sources where ~ isn‘t a dead key.